# Price Rule Condition: Product is new

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, date

Is it possible to not use a fixed date but just the "current date" as a condition for a price rule for promotions?

For example let's say I want to give a 10% discount to all new products.

I would like to add the simple condition of.
Set as New product from date <= today <= Set as new product to date

However, trying this I can only set fixed dates.
[image: Check if new product]

Is there a clever way around this perhaps?
Edit A dumb way is fine too :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way out-of-the-box to set it as you'd like to but there are few quick workarounds.

My first and favorite, would be too create a module that would in some kind of time intervals set particular products as new and after that take them and assign them to special category "New prodcts" (it doesn't have to be included in navigation).

Then the condition would be if Category is **(not?)** one of: New products. [depending on which way you'd like to go with that].

Second possibility would be to create a custom product attribute "New product" which would be updated by a module from time to time. Then use it inside a promotion like: New product is: true/false.

Probably there are tons more but these two seems to be easiest and not overthinked.

Comment: Was already working towards solution 2. Maybe I'll publish the module when done.